# Spring security CSRF protection and JWT based authorization

Tags: angular, spring-boot, csrf

I have been trying to find out how vulnerable my (spring boot 3.1.x) app would be without CSRF protection if I have an oauth2 authorization flow in it (there is a keycloak server for it). From what I see, this authorization approach would make my app CSRF invulnerable. However I found multiple mentions that still this approach is XSS vulnerable, hence I tried out to configure CSRF in the application, based on the Spring Security 6.0 documentation. The front-end is angular, I am using `CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();`, whatnot. I am seeing that the flow is properly passing in the XSRF header in case of a POST for instance, and everything works. However, I see that if I do a postman call and provide only the Bearer token, the thing still pass. It is like the XSRF token is totally ignored. I found no documentation about what is going on here, but my gut tells me that the CSRF has been turned off implicitly with the spring's oauth settings I have.

Anybody have any idea what is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

> my gut tells me that the CSRF has been turned off implicitly with the authorization flow. Anybody have any idea what is wrong with this approach?

It seems that you are mixing (confusing?) OAuth2 client (with login) and resource server configurations. The two are very different (Spring provides with distinct boot starters for a reason):

- security for clients with login (initiating `authorization_code` flow on the authorization server) is based on sessions (which make it vulnerable to CSRF)
- security for resource servers is based on access tokens. Sessions can (should?) be disabled, which makes it invulnerable to CSRF.

If you send Postman request with a Bearer Authorization header, then it behaves as an OAuth2 client sending a request to an OAuth2 resource server.

But this Postman request is very different from what an Angular request should be: **an Angular application should not be an OAuth2 (public) client**: [you should be using OAuth2 (confidential) client on the server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). Such client could be `spring-cloud-gateway` configured with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and the `TokenRelay=` filter, or your REST API configured as a client instead of a resource server (which I don't recommand as it would remove the natural scalability and fault tolerance of stateless resource servers).

This means that Angular app should not be an OAuth2 actor at all (it is just a "frontend"): **requests between Angular and a Spring OAuth2 client with login are secured with session, which make it vulnerable to CSRF** (again, Spring OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login` should always be protected against CSRF).

So it is likely that your application(s) security conf is not following the best practices, but as you don't provide it, I can't tell you what should be changed.

CSRF can arm on requests which change application state. Spring Security assumes that your HTTP verbs usage is correct, and checks for the CSRF tokens only for `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests. So, don't expect an error because of a missing CSRF token on a `GET` request. Again, as your question doesn't expose what kind of request is the one you send with Postman, this are just guesses.

Starting from Spring Security 6, [setting a cookie repo with `HttpOnly=false` is not enough anymore: you have to define a filter too](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_a_single_page_application_with_cookiecsrftokenrepository). Quote from the doc:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    http
        // ...
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        )
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

private static final class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        // Render the token value to a cookie by causing the deferred token to be loaded
        csrfToken.getToken();

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am aware of this stuff. The angular app uses the CSRF tokens well and accordingly, but when I do a postman call I see that the spring app doesn't care the CSRF token. In the meantime I found something as a lead. My assumption was that the oauth2 settings in spring side basically turned off CSRF validation.

Comment: Then found this but I won't post it as an answer yet, will dig deeper on monday but I already tried out a suggested workaround and I do see http 401 when I don't send the CSRF. Which is not a "valid" answer imho but works https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8668

Comment: When a request contains an access token, this token should protect against CSRF (and also breach if rotated frequently enough). But, again, your Angular app should not send access tokens (it should not even have access to it), and the application directly facing Angular should not be a resource server (it should be a client). Edited to clarify a bit.

Comment: The angular app is not the resource server, it's a frontend app, a client to our backend which IS the resource server and a public client on a keycloak server. See also my answer I gave on this question because that turns out to be the issue

Comment: I might have used really wrong terminology in the question then if it is so misunderstandable.

Comment: Oh and thanks to trying to answer. I do remember your username in various places, on was exactly for keycloak and spring

Comment: Of course your angular app is not a resource server! What can you make think I wrote that? What I write is your Angular app should not be an OAuth2 client (it should not be OAuth2 at all and have no access to tokens, see the link to the post from Spring Security team in my answer). I also write that the Spring app directly facing the Angular app (call it BFF, gateway or whatever you like) should be an OAuth2 client and not a resource server as requests from Angular should not have a token but a session cookie).

Comment: What I also try to explain is you you shouldn't mix OAuth2 client (login) and OAuth2 resource server configurations in the same filter-chain, it is too different. You don't care to protect a stateless resource server against CSRF, but you have to protect an OAuth2 client with login against CSRF. So follow Spring Security team directive, use a confidential client on server (not public in browser) and don't give the Angular app access to tokens. [Complete sample](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff)

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found so far and was mostly assuming it from behavior is that the spring security 6.0 + oauth2 settings turns off CSRF validation and that was strenghten by this github issue

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8668

I used the proposed workaround and it did an error on missing CSRF but it was just http 401 which can be misleading. I do some other tests later but I think this is the solution.